# Autonomous navigation with turtlebot. Troubles through doors

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the navigation stack on turtlebot, but when I try to navigate autonomously in the map my robot **can not go through doors.** I suspect that's because of the inflated objects. If you look at what's being shown in rviz the blue part of each part of the door is touching at the middle.

Does somebody know where I can change the inflated objects to a smaller range?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12232/autonomous-navigation-with-turtlebot.-troubles-through-doors./) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-05**:
Can you post your navigation stack configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Direct answer to your question is `turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_navigation/costmap_common_params.yaml` (as in @Pi Robot's comment too).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is solved.

I've changed this line:

else if(distance <= cell_inscribed_radius_)

for this one:

else if(distance <= cell_inscribed_radius_**/2**)

so the inflated objects are half big now.

---

Originally posted by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) with karma: 318 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-12-06**:
I filed this ticket (https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/97) yesterday which I think is related.  (The TurtleBot's radius is set to 2x what it should be.)